# Where is information on What's Coming in ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

Every year I need to make a case to my employer as to why it is essential we continue to pay maintenance.

To justify this investment, I need to have some idea about what's coming so **I began googling what's new in ArcGIS 10.3 Desktop and I can't find any concrete information.**

Does anyone know where I can find this info?

I understand ArcGIS Pro comes bundled with 10.3, but at this time I am only interested in new features, fixes and advancements in ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop and its extensions.

Comment: I too have had a similar reminder that my maintenance has lapsed and I should get a new maintenance so I can get 10.3. I was thinking of holding back until 10.3 is actually released...

Comment: Usually, we were able to find out at regional conferences, the general hype, discussions and ESRI's "What's coming" bits but now the whole thing seems to be shrouded in mystery this time around and I am seriously considering dropping maintenance either way, especially given the advances in QGIS in the last few years.

Comment: Everything I've read says it will be released early 2015. Check https://esriaustralia.com.au/products-arcgis-software-10-3 and https://esriaustralia.com.au/products-arcgis-software-10-3-pre-release-faqs

Comment: If you have access to the pre-release, you could install it on some machine and look into the Help system, I believe it should be shipped together with the pre-release.

Comment: There was considerable extra text in this question that was not germane to getting it answered, and instead looked likely to promote discussion rather than focussed Q&A, so it has been removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This PDF, which has too many new features to list, is available:

**http://pro.arcgis.com/en/documentation/whats-new/whats_new_in_arcgis.pdf**

From [System Requirements for 10.3](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/get-started/system-requirements/arcgis-desktop-system-requirements.htm), the key part is

> When running in a 64-bit environment, ArcGIS for Desktop, ArcGIS
>   Engine, and ArcReader run as a 32-bit application.

**ArcGIS Pro** will be the first application to run in a 64-bit environment as a 64-bit application.